# How can I use local JSON to dynamically create a page in my app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a JSON file of the format :

```
{
  "Name": "Hello John",
  "Description": "Profile Text",
  "URL": "//apply now link ",
  "Orientation": "Landscape",
  "1024x500": "//profile picture link",
},
```

Now I want to create the page shown below when the specific tile in my gridView iOS clicked. For eg. if the user clicks the Hello John Tile I want to create the Page(Shown in Image) which will have the title of Hello John and an Image of John(link 3) and a url that opens Johns profile. 
However the json file has more than 200 such profiles and I want dynamically create a page that will open when the respective gridView Tile is clicked. There is also an orientation requirement that needs to be called from the JSON file.

This is the Page I want to dynamically create:
[image]

This is the Grid View. The Grid View is already Indexed and has the title and the image. Only the next page has to be called using Json.
[image]

This is the code for the Page:

```
    class CourseInfoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _CourseInfoScreenState createState() => _CourseInfoScreenState();
    }

    class _CourseInfoScreenState extends State<CourseInfoScreen>
        with TickerProviderStateMixin {

      Future launchURL(String url) async {
        const url = '//apply now link ';
        if (await canLaunch(url)) {
          await launch(url, forceWebView: true, forceSafariVC: true);
        } else {
          throw 'Could not launch $url';
        }
      }

      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final double tempHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
            (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2) +
            24.0;

        return Container(
          color: DesignCourseAppTheme.nearlyWhite,
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                        child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                            //if(index==1){}
                            "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/young-man-face-angry-facial-260nw-510023299.jpg",
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill, // use this
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 16, 
          right: 16, 
          bottom: 18, 
          top: 16
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Hello John',
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "Netflix",
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 35,
                letterSpacing: 0.27,
                color: HexColor('FFFF8C3B')
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      Expanded(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            print('pressed');
            _interstitialAd?.show();
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => WebviewScaffold(
                url:"//apply now link to be inserted here",

               //details of the Webview Scafflod 
appBar: AppBar(
                                                        leading: new IconButton(
                                                          icon: new Icon(
                                                              Icons.arrow_back),
                                                          onPressed: () {
                                                            Navigator.pop(
                                                                context);
                                                          },
                                                        ),
                                                        backgroundColor:
                                                            Color(0xFFFF8C3B),
                                                        title: const Text(
                                                          "Greedy Gnomes",
                                                        ),
                                                      ),                     

          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Apply Now',
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "Netflix",
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 18,
                letterSpacing: 0.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),

    }
```

Comment: There is a gap in your code towards the end. I've put in a comment inside. Can you please correct the issue?

Comment: the missing code were some ui details of the web view Scaffold. Ive added it you can have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, with your data but not your layout, of how you can take the data, list it in a grid and on tap on each item move to a detailed view of that item:

```
class PageFromJson extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageFromJsonState createState() => _PageFromJsonState();
}

class _PageFromJsonState extends State<PageFromJson> {


  List<Map> itemList = [
    {
      "Name": "Hello John",
      "Description": "Profile Text",
      "URL": "//apply now link ",
      "Orientation": "Landscape",
      "1024x500": "//profile picture link",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Hello Ana",
      "Description": "Profile Text",
      "URL": "//apply now link ",
      "Orientation": "Landscape",
      "1024x500": "//profile picture link",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Hello Alice",
      "Description": "Profile Text",
      "URL": "//apply now link ",
      "Orientation": "Landscape",
      "1024x500": "//profile picture link",
    },
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: itemList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => _goToItemViewer(itemList[index]),
          child: ItemCard(
            item: itemList[index]
          ),
        );
      },
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2
      ),
    );
  }

  void _goToItemViewer(item){
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
      return ItemViewer(item: item);
    }));
  }
}

class ItemCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map item;

  ItemCard({
    @required this.item,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.blueGrey,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(item['Name']),
          Text(item['1024x500']),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemViewer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map item;

  ItemViewer({
    @required this.item,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(item['Name']),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(item['Name']),
            Text(item['Description']),
            Text(item['URL']),
            Text(item['Orientation']),
            Text(item['1024x500']),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```